How to properly check if location service was turned on, after back from the settings to app
I have an app, which should check on start, whether the location service is on, or off. I've tried to play around with AlerDialog, and sending user to the settings via Intent, but it doesn't work as I'd like to.
I've changed approach, because I'd like to have location service checked after user will be back from settings, and wrote down following function:
    @Composable
private fun TEST() {

    val locationManager =
        LocalContext.current.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager

    val locationPermissionLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        onResult = {
            Log.i(TAG, "TEST: ${locationManager.isLocationEnabled}")
        })
    val context = LocalContext.current

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
        locationPermissionLauncher.launch(Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS))
    }
}

Now, is it good approach? You can't directly register activity for Intent service result, right? How I may approach it properly?

LaunchedEffect will not work in that case, as it will not be triggered again when your app is coming back into the foreground. Instead, you can observe the Activity Lifecycle Methods in Jetpack Compose as follows:
val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current
val lifecycleState by lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.currentStateFlow.collectAsState()

val isPermissionGranted = 
    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) 
       == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED


if(!isPermissionGranted) {
    // setup rememberLauncherForActivityResult
    // launch Activity
}

LaunchedEffect(lifecycleState) {
    if (lifecycleState == Lifecycle.State.RESUMED ) {
        // Activity was resumed. This is called when user returns to App.
        // Check here again whether the permission is granted now.
    )
}

